# How to setup a project for Clean architecture in gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, clean-architecture

So I was going through clean architecture in android, really liked it how people even create separate projects for domain, data and presentation layer. I tried to create my own project for clean architecture but couldn't set up different projects for domain, data and presentation layers.

How can I accomplish this kind of project architecture?
https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one project as your main project of type Android Application Project. The separate layers can be added as library modules to your main project.

[image]

[image]

Then you just need to add these library modules to your gradle file as dependencies. Android studio will usually take care of that. But just in case you needed to change the order of dependencies, you can do that in the gradle files of each module.